# Typescript: How to satisfy union type with function and arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, union-types, strong-typing

The union of `(arg: string) => void` and `(arg: number) => void` is `(arg: never) => void`, because no value can be a `string` and a `number` at the same time. But how can I work around this issue in the following example?

```
type Test<T, U> =
  | {
      func: (arg: T) => void;
      data: T;
    }
  | {
      func: (arg: U) => void;
      data: U;
    };

function test<T, U>(x: Test<T, U>) {
  x.func(x.data);
}
```

In this example, `x.data` should always be of the correct type to satisfy the function argument, but typescript can't see it and errors with `Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`.

**EDIT**: My use case is the following: Our application has some code to handle navigation between pages. Each possible page is represented by something like this:

```
type Route<T> = {
  extractData: (url: string) => T;
  encodeDataToURL: (data: T) => string;
  getTitle: (data: T) => string;
  render: (data: T) => DOM.Element;
}
```

The router handles all routes, so calling the current route's `extractData` yields `HomePageData | SearchPageData | ...`. When we would call `getTitle` or `render`, since it was the same object that produced the data, it should still work fine, but typescript seems oblivious to this.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using two types (T and U) to build the same, identical structure. Why not use a single type (just `type Test<T>`, removing `U` everywhere) and then call `test<number>({func: (arg: number) => {}, data: 0});` or `test<string>({func: (arg: string) => {}, data: ''});`? Am i missing something?

Comment: Please [edit] to show a use case that motivates the union type here.  Not all operations automatically support unions so you'd need to manually specify some things like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO27RW), and it's not clear why you'd bother.  What is the use case?

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi `Test<string | number>` is not the same thing as `Test<string> | Test<number>`?

Comment: I agree with @AlbertoFecchi that there seems to be no point in having that union.  Also, the error I get if I copy-paste your code is different than you say and quite more illuminating: "Argument of type 'T | U' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T & U'."